# Angular Observable and setTimeout Issue - Outputting Unexpected Value

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

I'm encountering an issue with my Angular code involving Observables and setTimeout. My goal is to update the 'active status' every minute for a specified duration, but my current implementation is yielding an unexpected result. When I run the code, I'm getting '2001 minutes ago' as the output, and I can't figure out why?.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'observable';
  activestatus: any = 'now';
  secondstatus: any = 'now';
  data: any;
  time = 2000;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = new Observable((observer) => {
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.time; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(i + ' minutes ago');
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

    this.data.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.activestatus = res;
    });
  }
}`

Issue:
I expect to see 'active status' updated every minute for the specified duration. However, the code is not working as intended, and the output is '2001 minutes ago.' I'd appreciate help in understanding and fixing this issue.

Additional Information:

Angular version: 16.2.2
```